# Выделение строки в DataGrid

Tags: c#

Имеется класс-наследник DataGrid MWF. В нем программно надо выделить строку (одну) по критерию. Код:

```
//for (var i=0; i<_newList.Count;i++)
//{
//    var am = _newList[i];
//    if (am.id == _SelId)
//    {
//        //DataGridRow row = AlarmMessagesDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
//        AlarmMessagesDataGrid.SelectedIndex = i;
//        break;

//    }

//}
foreach (AlarmMessage am in AlarmMessagesDataGrid.Items)
{
    if (am.id == _SelId)
    {
        AlarmMessagesDataGrid.SelectedIndex = AlarmMessagesDataGrid.Items.IndexOf(am);
        break;
    }
}
```

`AlarmMessagesDataGrid` - класс-наследник `DataGrid` (с возможностью фильтрации по столбцам). `_SelId` - критерий того, что данная строка должна быть выделена.

Сколько не бился - код не работает. Никаких ошибок не вылазит. В дебаге код проходися нормально. "Вручную" (щелчком по строке таблицы) выделение работает.

Уже не знаю, что делать (Закомментирован один из вариантов кода)

Comment: вот это `AlarmMessagesDataGrid.Items.IndexOf(am);` какое число возвращает?

Comment: Возвращает корректный номер требуемой строки. AlarmMessages - объект, которым заполняются строки Grid.